# Arxiv Journal Ref field updation guidelines and examples for published Conference papers

Tags: publications, conference, arxiv, open-access, ieee

ArXiv has a section called [Journal Ref](https://arxiv.org/help/prep#journal) where a researcher can add a publication reference for their paper published in a journal or proceedings. For a journal the rules and example provided is clear, which states:

> Indicate the volume number, year, and page number (or page range).

However for conferences, especially IEEE conferences, the proceedings are usually published in IEEE Xplore, and not in a proceedings book, thus they don't have a volume number, issue number etc.

Let's take my paper [here](https://doi.org/10.1109/RAICS51191.2020.9332513), published in IEEE RAICS 2020, as an example, what'd be an appropriate Journal ref for this? Thanks to @scaahu's comment, I was thinking of going with <Title, year, page range> as below:

> 2020 IEEE Recent Advances in Intelligent Computational Systems (RAICS), 2020, pp. 201-206

Should I drop the year, as it's already in the title, or does it not matter.

Currently, I was unable to find any related Questions when I searched online. Also, if you can give some more illustrative examples for Springer and Elsevier conferences too, what are the variations in those cases, I believe the answer would be even more helpful to future researchers.

Comment: Using the "Cite This" of the  IEEE link, I found this: A. J. Paul, "Recent Advances in Selective Image Encryption and its Indispensability due to COVID-19," 2020 IEEE Recent Advances in Intelligent Computational Systems (RAICS), Thiruvananthapuram, India, 2020, pp. 201-206, doi: 10.1109/RAICS51191.2020.9332513.

Comment: @scaaahu Thanks a ton, I've now proceeded to go to with <Title, year, page range>.